The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request
I just updated all i18next's related modules in the front end of our app to their latest versions ("react-i18next", "babel-plugin-i18next-extract", "i18next" et "i18next-http-backend".)
These are the older versions for each module and the latest ones that I got :
"i18next": "^21.8.10" => "^23.11.2"
"i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1" => "^2.5.0"
"react-i18next": "^11.17.2" => "^14.1.0"
"babel-plugin-i18next-extract": "^0.8.3" => "^0.10.0"

but I got this error :
System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.CheckSSLConfig(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Statsh.Server.Controllers.Api.ContextController.Index() in D:\TnPulses\SuiviRepos\29-02-24\Statsh\Statsh.Server\Controllers\Api\ContextController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method1394(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Statsh.Server.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in D:\TnPulses\SuiviRepos\29-02-24\Statsh\Statsh.Server\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I googled about that error but I didn't find a solution that can help but I think this config code from our C# backend might be related to this issue :
            services.AddAntiforgery(o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
            });

            services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
            });

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

I know nothing about C#. Does somebody has a clue what can be done to fix this ?

Basically, if you use Always then you must use HTTPS to make a request. If you want to be able to use HTTP then change it to SameAsReequest.
